# Функция rand() в генерирует постоянно одинаковые числа

Tags: c++

Пользуюсь компилятором Qt. Нужно составить одномерный массив из случайных чисел, но функция rand() генерирует каждый раз одинаковые числа, начиная с 41.

```
for (int i=0; i<N; i++)
{
    massive[i]=rand();
}
```

Comment: `srand(time(NULL))`?

Comment: `srand` вызвать один раз, в начале программы.

Comment: error: void value not ignored as it ought to be
         massive[i]=srand(time(NULL));

Comment: Нет, `srand()` нужен для инициализации базы, а генерацией значений занимается именно `rand()`. Как верно заметили, производите инициализацию единожды перед циклом.

Comment: Зачем в 2020 ранд? возьмите mt

Answer (score 2):

```
srand(time(NULL));        // инициализация генератора для текущего времени

for (int i=0; i<N; i++)
{
    massive[i]=rand();
}
```